# What kind of op amp is it? how do I calculate the VA voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier

the first value of Q1='0' (off). how can I calculate VA voltage, the  output of op amp ? I am not sure if is it like a buffer cause I've  never seen some buffer like this. thanks ahead for any help

[image]

this is what i get after i try to simulate how is possible the current flow with same voltage?? besided R1?

[image]

Comment: Hint, what is the effect of Q1 when the latch output is 0 and when it is 1?

Comment: I think when Q1 is 1 the VA voltage will be -Vin,(va=-vin), but I can't prove myself what is the value of VA in this case of Q1=0 @ThePhoton

Comment: Okay, good so far. How does the BJT act when the base voltage is 0?

Comment: cut off mode, yea i know that collector of bjt not connect the V+,(V+ free) that what makes me problem in my mind. @ThePhoton

Comment: This is why I circle in red what I will get after zero base voltage...

Comment: We can ignore the missing current limiting Rb for Q1, But the driving voltage is to Vin+ and Vin- matches that from the output, Va. So in each case what is Vin+ then Vin- finally Va becomes obvious.

Comment: I can't understand you sorry @SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: If Q1 is in cut-off, how much current flows through the 10 kohm resistor connected to the non-inverting input of the op-amp?

Comment: BTW, please add designators to your schematic so we can talk about "R1" or "R3" instead of "the 10 k resistor connected to the non-inverting input of the op-amp".

Comment: zero current  @ThePhoton

Comment: I try to simulate this red circle circuit, I know that V+=V- ,and the voltage in V- supposed to be Vin so the current will be zero in R1 how is it possible??

Comment: So, if there's no current through the resistor, then what's the voltage at the non-inverting input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94887/discussion-between-knowledge-and-the-photon).

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVQsEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vin+ is set to a fixed voltage Vout changes to null the input difference "error".

Iin to both Op Amp inputs is close to zero so we neglect this current.  Same for Q1 when OFF.  **Thus R1 has (almost pA~uA?) no current flowing thru it when Q1 is OFF.**

Comment: First -Thanks, it is understood why V+=Vin and the current will not flow thru it when Q1 is off, *BUT* why the current in R2,R3 neglected(i know that in op amp the current input is closed to zero but there is another path..

Comment: Only current input OA is neglected.  I(R2)=I(R3) always so if Vbat is 2 Vout must be -2 to get 0V on Vin-

Comment: but the voltage Va is equaled to Vin when Q1 is off....

Comment: Yes as said in RED text

Comment: This circuit looks like an over-complicated 1 shot on power up, but demonstrates the ability to invert voltages with a transistor.

Comment: yes, this is voltage to frequency circuit

Comment: Looks unstable to me. Since the overall feedback is positive

Comment: yes is unstable too, but you can control the  time of output voltage with linear changing of vin voltage that what i mean.

Comment: OK I see now.. Q1 Vce(sat) introduces small error but ok as Astable . Easier ways to do this.